# Connecting to BLE using MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm connecting to a `BLE` device using the `MAC` address.
The issue is, i have no way to know if the device is on/off or in range.
The `getRemoteDevice()` method return an object of `BluetoothDevice` in any scenario.
The only solution i'm thinking about is, to scan the devices in range and check if it contains my device `MAC` address.
Is there more proper way to do it?

Comment: Please find the following  link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: If you have dought ask me

Comment: to know if the device is in range, you have to scan it, or to try to connect to it. No other ways